# Check if multiple directories exist with bash script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, directory

I have a file with a list of directories and I need to find out if they actually exist on the system. It's quite a large list so I'd like to figure out how to automate the check.

The file is formatted with each directory on a new line:

```
/usr/bin
/usr/sbin
/bin
/sbin
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r dir; do
    if [[ -d $dir ]]; then
        echo "Dir exists"
    else
        echo "Dir $dir does not exist"
    fi  
done < dirs
```

Output on execution with this file as infile (`dirs`):

```
cat dirs
/usr/bin
/usr/sbin
/bin
/sbin

./checkDirs.sh 
Dir exists
Dir exists
Dir exists
Dir exists
```